# How RSS feed submitter softwares are able to submit feeds?

Tags: php, rss, authentication, feed

Well, recently i bought a software that submits RSS to various RSS directories. Some of the directories, when we visit manually through a internet browser, requires registrations to submit our feed (Most popular example of such directories is feedage dot com)
What made me wonder is, the software don't ask any login details while submitting my feed to 'feedage'!!!
Now, what i'd like to know is, how the software is able to submit my feed to feedage without loggin in ??

*if i can get the procedure then i'm planning to code a php script that will do the work for me from my server using cron job*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually websites like these have APIs, what this means is that the software can submit the feed in a way especially designed for the software. However, if you want to be sure, you should ask either the developer you bought the software from or feedage directly.

Answer (score 1):

Feedage.com doesn't have anything to block scripts from using it (no captcha), so you could write a program or script to access the page.

You should do some research on cURL (http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). You could use it to send data to the website with a PHP script.

Comment: Feedage do have a captcha (feedage.com/submit.php) + it is also requires to login before submitting the RSS feed.
Now, I'm wondering, whose account is used by the RSS submitter software while submitting my rss feed!!!

Comment: Oh, I see now. It must have an API.

Look at http://www.feedage.com/api/
It's forbidden and the 404 page is different, so it must exist. Maybe contact them and see if you can get what is required to use it